# Split a matrix into smaller matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of size 20*20. I want to split it into two sub-matrices of size 20*10.
If i use the following code:

```
 e
 f=mat2cell(e,[10,10],[10,10])
 celldisp(f)
```

i get four sub-matrices of size 10*10 and if i use the following code, i get two matrices of size 10*20.

```
 e
 f=mat2cell(e,[10,10])
 celldisp(f)
```

(where e is the matrix which i want to split)

How can i get two sub-matrices of size 20*10? Please help.

Comment: There are 400 elements in a 20x20 matrix, there are only 100 elements in a 10x10 matrix. How do you propose to split 400 elements into two matrices of 100 elements each ?

Comment: my mistake..it is 20*10..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do the following

```
f = mat2cell( e, 20, [10 10] );
```